# Should I use the Kernel Trick whenever possible for non-linear data?

Tags: machine-learning, svm, kernel-trick, heuristic

I recently learned about the use of the Kernel trick, which maps data into higher dimensional spaces in an attempt to linearize the data in those dimensions. Are there any cases where I should avoid using this technique? Is it just a matter of finding the right kernel function?

For linear data this is of course not helpful, but for non-linear data, this seems always useful. Using linear classifiers is much easier than non-linear in terms of training time and scalability.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> For linear data this is of course not helpful, but for non-linear data, this seems always useful. Using linear classifiers is much easier than non-linear in terms of training time and scalability.

@BartoszKP already explained why is kernel trick useful. To fully address your question however I would like to point out, that kernelization is **not the only option** to deal with non linearly separable data.

There are at least three good, common alternatives for **delinearization** of the model:

- Neutal network based methods, where you add one (or more) layers of processing units, able to transform your data into the linearly separable case. In the simplest case it is a sigmoid-based layer, which adds non-linearity to the process. Once randomly initialized they are getting updates during the gradient-based optimization of the upper layer (which actualy solves the linear problem).
- In particular - deep learning techniques can be used here to prepare data for further linear classification. It is very similar idea to the previous one, but here you first train your processing layers in order to find a good starting point for further **fine-tuning** based on training of some linear model.
- Random projections - you can sample (non linear) projections from some predefined space and train linear classifier on top of them. This idea is heavily exploited in so called **extreme machine learning**, where very efficient linear solvers are used to train a simple classifier on random projections, and achieve very good performance (on non linear problems in both classification and regression, check out for example **extreme learning machines**).

To sum up - kernelization is a great delinearization technique, and you **can** use it, when the problem is not linear, but this should not be blind "if then" appraoch. This is just one of at least few interesting methods, which can lead to various results, depending on the problem and requirements. In particular, ELM tends to find very similar solutions to those given by kernelized SVM while in the same time can be trained rows of magnitude faster (so it scales up much **better** than kernelized SVMs).

Answer (score 10):

The price you pay for the Kernel Trick in general, for linear methods, is having worse generalization bounds. For a linear model its [VC dimension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VC_dimension) is also linear in terms of the number of dimensions (e.g. VC dimension for a Perceptron is `d + 1`).

Now, if you will perform a complex non-linear transform to a high dimensional space the VC dimension of your hypothesis set is significantly larger, as it's now linear in terms of the number of dimensions in the new, high dimensional space. And with it, the generalization bound goes up.

[Support Vector Machines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_vector_machine) exploit the Kernel Trick in the most efficient way, by doing two things:

- the generalization bound for hard-margin SVM models is related to the number of Support Vectors, and for soft-margin is related to the norm of the weight vector - so it can be irrelevant in the first case, and almost irrelevant in the second case. No matter how "big" the kernel target space is, you don't loose anything/much in terms of the generalization (references: (i) [C. Cortes and V. Vapnik. Support vector networks.
  Machine Learning, 20:273–297, 1995](http://image.diku.dk/imagecanon/material/cortes_vapnik95.pdf) ; (ii) [Shawe-Taylor, J.; Cristianini, N., "On the generalization of soft margin algorithms," Information Theory, IEEE Transactions on , vol.48, no.10, pp.2721,2735, Oct 2002](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download;jsessionid=CF8FC90426EB18AF13F95C9E67DBC0B0?doi=10.1.1.23.8439&rep=rep1&type=pdf)).
- SVMs find the separation plane that maximizes the margin, and this further simplifies the hypothesis set (we don't consider every possible separating plane, just those that maximize the margin). Simple hypothesis set also leads to better generalization bounds (this is related to the first point, but it's more intuitive).

Comment: "is also linear in terms of the number of weights" in terms of space dimension, not the number of weights. You can have linear classifier parametrized with as many weights as you want, but its VC dimension is still d+1 (where d is space dimensionality).

"the VC dimension for SVM models is related to the number of Support Vectors " How exactly is VC dimension realted to the number of SV? I'm aware of the hard margin bound, but afaik in the soft margin case there is no such relation. Even in Radamacher's complexity bounds you won't find the number of SVs as a variable.

Comment: Also "so its irrelevant how "big" the kernel target space is, you don't loose anything in terms of the generalization bound" is as far as I know completely false. High dimensional spaces will lead to loose of generalization capabilities, even with such strongly regularized model as SVM.

Comment: @lejlot Thanks, corrected the first two mistakes. I need some time to relate to your last two remarks - I'll try to improve the answer and provide some sources, after I recheck my information :)

Comment: @lejlot Right, I confused the VC dimension with the generalization bound - also fixed, and with added reference.

Comment: It is now almost correct, but what is the reason for assumption, that size of the kernel space in irrelevant? Take any dataset, run a SVM with RBF kernel and C->inf and you will overfit badly. It is not so simple. Number of dimensions in the feature space is **relevant**, yet it can be controlled with C (as an upper bound of lagrange multipliers). In particular - VC dimension for SVM with RBF is infinity, and generalization bound (Vapnik's) is useless (Radamacher could work but this is whole different story).

Comment: @lejlot It says it's "almost irrelevant" for the soft-margin case - just for the reason you speak of: what's relevant in the bound for the soft-margin case is the norm of the weight vector (which is controlled by C). So regardless of how many features kernel space has, C controls the bound. That's why it's "almost irrelevant".

Comment: AFAIK, it is **rellevant** for **generalization bounds** you are talking about. I agree, that in practise, C works well in terms of limiting the structural risk, but it is not a direct consequence of Vapnik's generalization bounds.

Comment: @lejlot I've given another reference - they provide a bound for soft-margin case explicitly, and it's not dependent on the number of dimensions.

Comment: Very good reference. I revoke my "vote", as it would become a long theoretical discussion regarding fat bound, or gap tolerant bound, which does not involve dimensionality "per se", yet the size of the margin is dimensionality dependent (in particular, size of the margin is the function of dimensionality, as in case of the rbf - it is an inverse of integral of linear combination of gaussian distributions, right? It becomes much less "rigid" than in case of lower dimension).

Comment: @lejlot Yes, I admit that it all doesn't look *that* optimistic as in first version of my answer. Thanks for your valuable input!

Answer (score 6):

I will try to provide a non-technical answer to your question.

Indeed, linear should be preferred and should be the first choice for the reasons you mention, training time, scalability, plus ease on interpreting the final model, choice of working on primal or dual, more tolerance to overfitting etc.

If the linear model doesn't result in satisfactory performance, then you can try non-linear solutions. Some trade-offs to consider include:

- the choice of kernel. This is not obvious, usually you need to test different options
- there is the danger of overfitting the training set. Actually it is pretty easy to overfit if you want. To avoid overfitting you need a stronger evaluation framework (you need to measure the variance/stability of performance on unseen data) and you need enough data in order to be able to do proper model selection
- you work on dual, and thus you can't interpret the final model, i.e., you can't claim that feature X is more important than feature Y etc.
- training time is increased with the volume of data (less with number of features since it's in the dual)

Comment: That's an interesing insight on "working with dual" leading to an inability to claim feature importances. Would you have some reference to material explaining further?